# How can I write these sentence to avoid ambiguity?

Tags: linguistics

How can i disambiguate these  sentences?

> 1. The design has big squares and circles.
> 2. they found a book on Hafez street.
> 3. Its drinking water.

I can't find the other meaning of these sentence.

Comment: Hello, Mahdiyeh. This question is not really suitable for ELU. I'll help you with question 1. 1a The design has big squares and big circles. 1b 1.The design has circles and big squares.

Comment: Number 3 is not a complete sentence.

Comment: No 2. Either they found a book when they were on Hafez Street, or they found a book **about** [on] Hafez Street.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - The design has big squares and moves around in circles.

Comment: No 3 should probably read "It's drinking water." Either it [an animal] is drinking water, or it [the water] is drinkable.

Comment: @HotLicks Ooh! Nice! Well spotted.

Comment: No. 2: They might  have found a book for sale by a vendor (located) on Hafez Street (or possibly in the library), or they might have found a book lying on Hafez Street.

Answer (score 0):

1. The design's circles and squares are big.

   The design has big circles and small/normal squares.

   The design has big squares and small/normal circles.

(the last two aren't the most elegant)

2. While shopping on Hafez street they found a book.

   They found a book lying on Hafez street.

   They found a book about Hafez street.
3. (assuming you meant **it's** drinking water)

   It drinks water.

   It is drinkable/potable water.